# Minecraft drops fps below 30 while cpu and gpu arent fully utilized

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently installed minecraft and I noticed alot of FPS drops happening very commonly, while the CPU and the GPU arent fully utilized. I tried turning off some settings in the Nvidia controlpanel but that didnt do anything.

Here is a screenshot of both programs.

[image: Minecraft and Res.Monitor]

Any idea what I can do to fully utilize my resources for the game ?

Comment: What about settings in the game? Have you tried tweaking any of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minecraft isn't... super well programmed, unfortunately it (mostly) only runs on a single core of your processor.

You seem to have a quad-core processor from your screenshot, 25% of that is one core fully utilized, so your CPU is maxed out on a single core. GPU usage is capped by your CPU (and minecraft isn't super GPU intensive anyway).

Comment: Funny tho, ive had the game before and it didnt have this issue. On the same computer, actually I changed my harddrive and its even faster now, so it makes no sense :D thanks anyway for the info, no multicore computing with minecraft i guess thats fun :D